# Making a responsive collapsable navigation bar. I am having difficulty getting the Javascript to work on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, frontend

I am creating a collapsible navigation bar for my websites mobile view. In the mobile view, I have a header with a logo and an icon on the right. The user can then click the icon to access the other website links.

When I comment out "display none" it does show that all of the other links are there underneath the logo and icon. I ran my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript through the W3C code validator and it came back with "no errors shown". My html file, CSS file, and JS file all seem to be in the appropriate folders as well.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
<title>Responsive Design</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='styles/styleresponsive.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/responsive.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/01c3568935.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- There's nothing here! -->

<nav class="navbar">

    <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </span>

    <a href="#" class="logo"> Logo<!-- <img src='images/stars.jpg' alt="logo" /> --> </a>

    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">

        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-links1"><img src='images/stars.jpg' alt="Art" /></a>

        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-links2"><img src='images/stars.jpg' alt="Code" /></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-links3"><img src='images/stars.jpg' alt="Dogs" /></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-links4"><img src='images/stars.jpg' alt="Contact" /></a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
/* So, testing for mobile, tablet, and desktop */

*{
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
box-sizing: border-box;
}

 /* Mobile Styles */

 @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {

body{
    background-color: #F09A9D; /* Red */
}
/* Here is where that Navigation bar gets tricky */

.navbar {
    font-size: 18px; 
    background-color: #5995DA; 
    width: 100%; 
}

.navbar-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; 
    right: 20px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px; 
}

/* Hide the menu so it's not visible by default */

.main-nav {
    list-style-type: none; /* Specifies the type of list-item marker */
    /* display: none; /* Not displayed */
} 

/* Styles the navigation links & logo */

.nav-links1,
.nav-links2,
.nav-links3,
.nav-links4,
.logo {
    text-decoration: none; 
/*  list-style-type: none; /* Removes the default list text underline */
}

/* Styles the list */

.main-nav li {
    text-align: center; /* Aligns text center */
    margin: 15px auto;
    height: 100px; 
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block; 
    font-size: 22px; 
    margin-top: 10px; 
    margin-left: 20px; 
    height: 100px; 
}

.active {
    display: block; 
}
```

**JS**

```
/* Now lets make this responsive with JS */

let mainNav = document.getElementById("js-menu"); 

let navBarToggle = document.getElementById("js-navbar-toggle"); 

navBarToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {

    mainNav.classList.toggle("active");

});
```

I expect to be able to click on the icon and for the other navigation links to "collapse". Instead, this navigation bar seems stagnant.

[Demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO0GR.png)

Edit: The weird thing is, when I test my original code and the code with the edits suggested on codepen, it works. When I test it with the firefox and Safari developer inspector, it does not work. On the Safari JavaScript Console, it says "Not allowed to load local resource" for the Stars image. Is this what's wrong?

Edit two: Tried it without the stars.jpg. Just made each link look like

```
"<li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-links1">Art<!--<img src='images/stars.jpg' alt="Art"/> --></a>
        </li>"
```

to "test" it.

In the Safari JavaScript console, it says "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'navBarToggle.addEventListener')

In the FireFox JavaScript console, it says "TypeError: navBarToggle is null"

If this code will work on codepen, why does it not seem to work when I try to open the file from my own computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO :)

I think I see what the problem is. The problem is that the rule for `.main-nav` still applies, even when you toggle the `.active` class.

There are probably a lot of different ways to fix this. But one simple way to fix this would be to have a class `.mobile-inactive` instead. The nav menu starts with this class by default. You toggle this when the user clicks on your toggle `#js-navbar-toggle`.

In the mobile rules (the media query) I updated your `.main-Nav` CSS rule and added a new one for a class called `.inactive`. You can remove the `.active` rule because it will no longer be used:

So your the nav menu should be

```
<ul class="main-nav mobile-inactive" id="js-menu">
```

The rest of the HTML is unchanged.

Updated CSS:

```
/* So, testing for mobile, tablet, and desktop */

{
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
box-sizing: border-box;
}

 /* Mobile Styles */

 @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {

body{
    background-color: #F09A9D; /* Red */
}
/* Here is where that Navigation bar gets tricky */

.navbar {
    font-size: 18px; 
    background-color: #5995DA; 
    width: 100%; 
}

.navbar-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; 
    right: 20px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px; 
}

/* Hide the menu so it's not visible by default */

.main-nav {
    list-style-type: none; /* Specifies the type of list-item marker */

} 

/* Styles the navigation links & logo */

.nav-links1,
.nav-links2,
.nav-links3,
.nav-links4,
.logo {
    text-decoration: none; 
/*  list-style-type: none; /* Removes the default list text underline */
}

/* Styles the list */

.main-nav li {
    text-align: center; /* Aligns text center */
    margin: 15px auto;
    height: 100px; 
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block; 
    font-size: 22px; 
    margin-top: 10px; 
    margin-left: 20px; 
    height: 100px; 
}

.mobile-inactive {
    display: none; 
}
```

The updated javascript:

```
/* Now lets make this responsive with JS */

let mainNav = document.getElementById("js-menu"); 

let navBarToggle = document.getElementById("js-navbar-toggle"); 

navBarToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {

    mainNav.classList.toggle("mobile-inactive");

});
```

Comment: Thank you! I made the updates you suggested and traced the html and css relationship to the JavaScript file. Weirdly, it still does not seem to work.

Comment: I have my files stored as follows: Desktop->Web Design->Portfolio. My html files are in my portfolio file and a copy of my JS file. I also have my JS file in a "scripts" file, and my css in the "styles" file in portfolio.

Comment: This is what I have in my header: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>

    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>

    <title>Responsive Design</title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='styles/styleresponsive.css'/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="responsive.js"></script>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/01c3568935.js"></script>

  </head>

Comment: The weird thing is, when I use my edited code on code pen, it will work. When I use my edited code on my laptop, it won't. I'm testing the mobile view with the FireFox Inspector tool. JavaScript is enabled for FireFox.

Comment: If you get an error, it's likely that there is a typo in the file names or files are in the wrong the place.

Comment: If the code is working fine in Codepen, then I think the problem is that something isn't being loaded. This is pretty easy to check. Just open up the console in Firefox. The shortcut is control + shift + c, or you can find it in the "tools" menu under "Web Developer". If there is any kind of error loading a script, then that will show up in the console. You might have to refresh the page for it to show anything. While in the console, also try to click on the "style editor" tab, which will give you info about any CSS files that failed to load.